# Javascript Conversion of LEFT OUTER JOIN Query Result

Tags: javascript, node-postgres

I am using node-postgres to retrieve the results of a LEFT OUTER join query:

```
SELECT S.SEASON_ID, S.SEASON_NAME, I.ITEM_NAME, I.NOTE FROM T_SEASON S LEFT OUTER JOIN T_ITEM I ON S.SEASON_ID = I.SEASON_ID;
```

The resultset is going to look like this:

```
[
 {
   season_id:1, 
   season_name: "season 1", 
   item_name:"item1", 
   item_note: "text"
 }, 
 {
   season_id:1, 
   season_name: "season 1", 
   item_name:"item2", 
   item_note: "text"
 }, 
 {
   season_id:2, 
   season_name: "season 2", 
   item_name:"item3", 
   item_note: "text"
 }
]
```

What I need to do is break this into an array of "season" objects as follows:

```
[
 {
   seasonId: 1, 
   season_name: "season 1", 
   items: [
      {item_name: "item1", item_note: "text"},
      {item_name: "item2", item_note: "text"}
   ]
 }, 
 {
   seasonId: 2, 
   season_name: "season2", 
   items: [
      {item_name: "item3", item_note: "text"}
   ]
 }
]
```

In order words, "item" is a child collection of a season object.

I'm looking for the easiest way to do this. Lodash is available to me.

Comment: FYI I think you have a few typos... `item_name="item1"` should be `item_name:"item1"` yes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [**reduce**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

Create a key based on `season_id`. check if the key if it exists than push value in items of that particular key if not than create a new key with appropriate values. At the end just take the values out of object to get desired output.

```js
let data = [{season_id:1, season_name: "season 1", item_name:"item1", item_note: "text"}, {season_id:1, season_name: "season 1", item_name:"item2", item_note: "text"}, {season_id:2, season_name: "season 2", item_name:"item3", item_note: "text"}]

let output = data.reduce(( op, {season_id, item_name, item_note, season_name }) => {
  if(op[season_id]){
    op[season_id].items.push({item_name,item_note})
  } else {
    op[season_id] = {
      season_id,
      season_name,
      items: [{item_name,item_note}]
    }
  }
  return op
},{})

console.log(Object.values(output))
```

Comment: That worked. I had been trying to do it using _groupBy() in lodash and iterating those results, but was reasonably sure there was a better solution.